# ODBC 5.1 Driver [mysqld-5.1.41] Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, vb6, odbc

here's the code

```
Public Sub DeleteRoom(Room_ID As String)
 Dim CNo As Object
    Set CNo = SQLDNSCONNECT("TEST")
     Dim RSo As Recordset
    Set RSo = New Recordset
    Dim msql As String
     With CNo
        .Open

        If RSo.State = adStateOpen Then RSo.Close

           msql = "DELETE * FROM Room WHERE Room_ID='" & Room_ID & "'"

           RSo.Open msql, CNo
           MsgBox "Record(s) Deleted", vbInformation, ""
        End With
End Sub
```

The error is the "RSo.State = adStateOpen Then RSo.close"

I don't know why but it really seems right.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your delete query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

The `DELETE` clause does not accept columns:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Just remove the `*`:

```
DELETE FROM Room WHERE Room_ID=...
```

Comment: Just curious, how would that solve the error the OP experiences since it occurs on the line before the SQL statement?

Comment: @JP. Perhaps it's unrelated. However, we don't really know the exact error message so I'm guessing from the question title, assuming that the ODBC driver will only throw syntax errors for SQL queries.

Comment: OK. You're probably right but I was just going by what the OP said. Thanks.